# How to install another apk without icon launcher in another app

Tags: android, installation

I want to install another applications from my App, likes Google Play. When applications installed, I want to remove their icon launcher (my application will manage them). Can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean your application did not have an icon launcher after putting it in an apk?

Comment: No, my app will install another apps. When another apps installed, I want to remove their icon launcher.

Comment: You cannot change or remove their icon launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot manage another APK's files from within yours, as it would be a security risk. If you wanted to manage the apps from your app however you could create intents to launch them from your application using where (just replace the String with the name of the launch activity defined by the applications android manifest):

```
Intent launch = ("otherApplicationActivity");
startActivity(launch);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can make launcher icon for app in mainfest.xml

```
`    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

/>
```

`